# Alternate to regular expressions for parsing HTML page for links

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So I am trying to build a web crawler. I have started by passing the request and getting all the HTML of the page in response.

Next I thought of using regular expressions for extracting links from the HTML page. However the more I try to learn them the more tricky them seem.

Are there any alternatives to regular expressions (it may seem a discussion question but it is not I have searched the internet and haven't found a satisfactory answer).

Comment: you want the HTML utility pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the most famous library for parsing HTML in .NET .

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can't be used for HTML parsing (see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), use proper HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack :

http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack